# How to disable HDR on YouTube videos in Safari for Mac?

Tags: safari, youtube

My Intel iMac is literally dying (strong fans) when I play YouTube videos with HDR. Alas, YouTube interface doesn't allow to choose a video without HDR (all resolution in the menu have HDR). But, when I play the same video on my old iPad, it clearly doesn't show the HDR version of the video. So YouTube has a non HDR version for all resolutions (this can also be shown with the `yt-dlp` command line, see https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp).

How to force YouTube on Safari on Mac to disable the HDR? Or how to kill the Safari ability to display HDR videos? I haven't seen nothing on the Develop menu on Safari (go to the Advanced settings of Safari to activate this menu). But perhaps there is a solution with a customised User Agent? If I choose Safari on iPhone as the User Agent in the Develop menu, the video is less choppy, but I'm unable to change the resolution (which is low).

Context: I know that haven more than 250 tabs opened on Safari doesn't help, but I don't own a computer for using it as a toy, and I have a lot of memory on my Intel iMac. If I haven't closed these tabs, it's because all have useful informations in it, and I currently need to quick access to these informations. So, with all these tabs opened, a 4K HDR video on YouTube nearly kills my iMac (all is slow when the video is played, for example, the clock on the menu bar, with the seconds which aren't updated all seconds).

Comment: Doesn’t YouTube provide you a gear icon on each video to select the quality?

Comment: @Allan I think that's what the OP meant by "resolution […] menu".

Comment: @Allan Yes, it's the "resolution menu". If you need a real example, see e. g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zo9dJFo8H8g (from the Dolby vision channel). I have to close the tab with this video in order to type this comment (because as I type few character per seconds, I takes few second to display each individual character!).